# Getting all sub menu li elements using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to get all menus and sub menus with jQuery.
I have code that gets the main menus 1 by 1, then I'm trying to run code that will get each menu's sub menus.

I've gotten it to list all the sub menus together, but for some reason it shows all sub menus as a single link.

You can see it here on the footer- http://techno-rezef.xcore.co.il/index.php?route=product/category&path=20

This is were i'm having trouble - EDITED = WORKING CODE = SOLVED

```
  jQuery('.six.columns.column').each(function() { // Get each main menu
      var currentCol = jQuery(this);
      var niddle = jQuery(this).children('h3').text();
      var getMainMenu = jQuery('#boss_menu > ul > li > a:contains("' + niddle + '")');
      var fiveArow = 1;

      // Get each sub menu
      getMainMenu.parent('li').find('.dropdown > .option > ul > li > a > span').each(function() {
          var subMenuURL = jQuery(this).parent('a').attr('href');

          if (fiveArow <= 5) { // Get the first 5 menus for each category
              addRow(subMenuURL, jQuery(this), currentCol);
              fiveArow = fiveArow + 1;
          }
      });
  });

  function addRow(subMenuURL, listSubMenus, currentMenu) {
      currentMenu.find('ul').append('<li><a href="' + subMenuURL + '">' + listSubMenus.text() + '</a></li>');
  }
```

Comment: I believe my problem is with the getMainMenu.parent('li').find but i couldn't get it done with 'children' instead

Comment: sometimes it helps to make a smaller example in http://jsfiddle.net. It helps you and those trying to answer. Instead of going through your web page. Can you re-create a simple case in jsfiddle and add it to the question?

Answer (score 0):

It shows them all as a single hyperlink because you are doing all of your gathering inside this function. You should take 
`getSubMenusHTML +=  '<li><a href="' + subMenuURL + '">' + listSubMenus.text() + '</li></a>';`

and put it in a separate function. Then, where it was in your function, call the function. Like this:

```
    jQuery('.six.columns.column').each(function() { // Get each main menu
    var niddle = jQuery(this).children('h3').text();
    var getMainMenu = jQuery('#boss_menu > ul > li > a:contains("' + niddle + '")');

    // Get each sub menu
    var listSubMenus = getMainMenu.parent('li').find('.option > ul > li > a > span');
    var subMenuURL = listSubMenus.parent('a').attr('href');

    addLink(subMenuURL, listSubMenus);
});

  function addLink(subMenuURL,listSubMenus) {
    getSubMenusHTML +=  '<li><a href="' + subMenuURL + '">' + listSubMenus.text() + '</a></li>';
  }
```

This is untested, but I am pretty sure this would fix the issue

Edit: Also, noticed that you had `<li><a></li></a>`. Not sure what issues it would cause off the top of my head, but you should close the  before

```
<li><a></a></li>
```

EDIT:
Instead of :

```
getSubMenusHTML +=  '<li><a href="' + subMenuURL + '">' + listSubMenus.text() + '</a></li>';
```

Do:

```
getSubMenusHTML.append('<li><a href="' + subMenuURL + '">' + listSubMenus.text() + '</a></li>');
```

And if it is a ul that you are adding these items to, then make getSubMenusHTML:

```
var getSubMenusHTML = $('#your_Ul_ID');
```

Comment: Thanks Kassan i tried your solution now and also tried it in few different ways but i keep getting the same result.. All the sub menus outputs as 1 single link

Comment: What is getSubMenusHTML? I don't see it defined.

Comment: Inside the each, var getSubMenusHTML = "";
i forgot to add that

Comment: Thanks Kassan, i'm sorry for the late reply it's holidays here.. Look on my first post, i edited the code there with the function but i'm getting the same results

Comment: I'm trying to play with it and still, this is the best i get.. I don't get it :\

Comment: I edited my first post with the full code again. I missed that you wrote me to use append instead of html but i'm still getting same results :(

Comment: Updated code again, please check after the // Get each sub menu. I added another loop but still not working for me.. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
Added another loop for each sub menu i want to output and fixed it.
now it works